# Error Code: 1052. Column 'ATTRIBUTE' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

When I attempt to run the bellow section, I get the following error message. I am still new to SQL so I am guessing that the issue is relatively simple, making you experts cringe just a little bit. Regardless, thank you so so much to anyone who replies.

```
SELECT DRINKER, COUNT(RATING)
FROM DRINKERS LEFT JOIN LIKES
ON LIKES.DRINKER = DRINKERS.DRINKER
WHERE LIKES.RATING < 0
GROUP BY LIKES.DRINK
ORDER BY DRINK ASC;
```

I get the error :

> 19:17:07    SELECT DRINKER, COUNT(RATING) FROM DRINKERS LEFT JOIN LIKES ON LIKES.DRINKER = DRINKERS.DRINKER WHERE LIKES.RATING < 0 GROUP BY LIKES.DRINK ORDER BY DRINK ASC LIMIT 0, 1000
>
> Error Code: 1052. Column 'DRINKER' in field list is ambiguous    0.00031 sec

Thanks for any help at all!

Comment: likes.drinker = drinkers.drinker is ok because drinker is qualified by table name elsewhere drinker is ambiguous.

Comment: The column with the name `DRINKER` exists in both tables. You must specify the table the value to be taken from? for example, `SELECT LIKES.DRINKER FROM ...`. Or use `JOIN .. USING` syntax - in this case the columns used for joining do not need in table alias qualifying. `RATING` field must be qualified anycase.

Comment: @P.Salmon See query text in the error message - the problem is in the output columns list. PS. The problem (1st query row was lost) was caused by wrong formatting. Edited.

Comment: PS. Why the grouping expression (`LIKES.DRINK`) is not included into output columns list?

Comment: It's good programming practice to always qualify all columns, at least when several tables are involved. Just like `DRINKERS.DRINKER` instead of just `DRINKER`.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should qualify *all* column references.  Because you are using `LEFT JOIN`, I am guessing that you want all drinkers returned.  Your `WHERE` clause limits the result set to only those drinkers with negative ratings.

If you want *all* drinkers, then that condition needs to move to the `ON` clause.  I also recommend table aliases:

```
SELECT D.DRINKER, COUNT(L.RATING)
FROM DRINKERS D LEFT JOIN
     LIKES L
     ON L.DRINKER = D.DRINKER AND
        L.RATING < 0
GROUP BY D.DRINKER
ORDER BY D.DRINKER ASC;
```