# How to use COUNT with JOIN in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to find the drinker, total number of times that the drinker rated drinks for all drinkers. I also need to include drinkers who haven't rated a drink. I need to use either JOIN or LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN operations.

Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT LIKES.DRINKER, COUNT(LIKES.RATING)
FROM LIKES JOIN ORDERS.DRINK = LIKES.DRINK
GROUP BY LIKES.DRINKER;
```

Here are the tables I'm trying to join:

```
CREATE TABLE LIKES( /* Drinkers like drinks */
DRINKER     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drinker name */
DRINK       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drink name   */
RATING      DECIMAL(1)  NOT NULL,   /* Rating of the drink  */
    CONSTRAINT LIKES_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(DRINKER, DRINK),
    CONSTRAINT LIKES_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY(DRINK) REFERENCES ALLDRINKS(DRINK),
    CONSTRAINT LIKES_DKEY2 FOREIGN KEY(DRINKER) REFERENCES DRINKERS(DRINKER));

CREATE TABLE ORDERS(    /* Drinkers visit pubs and consumes drinks */
DRINKER     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drinker name */
PUB         VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Pub name */
ODATE       DATE        NOT NULL,   /* Order date   */
DRINK       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drink name   */
DRINK_NO    DECIMAL(2)  NOT NULL,   /* A sequence number of a drink */
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(DRINKER, PUB, ODATE, DRINK, DRINK_NO),
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY(PUB, DRINK) REFERENCES SERVES(PUB, DRINK),
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY(DRINKER) REFERENCES DRINKERS(DRINKER)   );
```

Here is an example of the INSERT statements:

```
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('PETER', 'WHISKY', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('MARY', 'CHAMPAGNE', 5);

INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 7);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('MARY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
```

Comment: Why don't you and the guy that raised https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61816016/error-code-1052-column-attribute-in-field-list-is-ambiguous get together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had you try another syntax, on documentation this is written for inner join :

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.key = B.key
```

May be you want to do like :

```
SELECT LIKES.DRINKER, COUNT(LIKES.RATING)
FROM LIKES 
INNER JOIN LIKES ON ORDERS.DRINK = LIKES.DRINK
GROUP BY LIKES.DRINKER;
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be describing a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT D.DRINKER, COUNT(L.RATING)
FROM DRINKERS D LEFT JOIN
     LIKES L
     ON D.DRINKER = L.DRINKER 
GROUP BY D.DRINKER;
```

This is saying "keep all rows in the first table (`DRINKERS`), even those that don't match the `ON` condition).